# ERROR: Config value download_clang not defined in any .rc file

Tags: bazel, tensorflow-lite

With reference to ERROR: Config value download_clang is not defined in any .rc file .I am stuck in the same issue.I have tensorflow 2 and have checkout to branch r2.2 .I have the same error : ERROR: Config value download_clang  not defined in any .rc file  .Can anyone tell me which bazel version I should ideally install.I have tried 2.0 and 3.0 already

Answer (score 5):

Anyone stuck with this problem can try this : (It worked for me)
When you are configuring then when you are asked about building fresh release of Clang.Then answer N (No).